# Force absolute url in <a> (ignore base url) in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

In Angular app I have `<base href="/foo/bar/">` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

I want to create some list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <a ng-href="{{item}}" target="_blank">{{item}}</a>
  <a ng-href="{{item}}" download>{{item}}</a>
</div>
```

My items can look like this: `['example1.com', 'www.example2.com', 'http://www.example3.com', 'https://www.example4.com'];`

For `example3` and `example4` it works ok.
What is the best way to fix it for:

- `example1.com` - now it goes to `http://localhost/foo/bar/example1.com`
- `www.example2.com` -  now it goes to`http://localhost/foo/bar/www.example2.com`

How can I force it to use absolute url? It should work with `http`, `https` and with `download` attribute.

Comment: Well i'm not sure in understand, use `http://www.example.com` ?

Comment: `example1.com` isn't an absolute URL. If you want to force it then you have to guess what scheme you want to use and change it.

Comment: @MEGADEVOPS I import this items from external source. I can modify it with some regexp, but maybe there is easier way

Comment: make a filter see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623967/how-to-use-ng-href-with-absolute-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use:

```
fixUrl(item) {
    return '//' + item.replace(/^.*:\/\//, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah then you should use something like that :

```
if (strpos($url, 'http') == false) {
  $url = 'http//:' .$url;
}
```

It will add `http//:` in front of every URLs that doesn't have it.